# How to select without a table in Ecto?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

How do I do a very simple SQL `SELECT` query in Ecto that does not use a table?

For example, using the MySQL command-line client, I can do this:

```
mysql> select 0;
+---+
| 0 |
+---+
| 0 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How would I do the same in Ecto?  Maybe something like this?

```
q = ... # some no-op queryable?
MyApp.Repo.one(q, select: 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Ecto.Adapters.SQL](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html) module.

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(MyApp.Repo, "select 0", [])
```